# include relative path changes in class (strange behaviour)

Tags: php

I don't want to use autoload!

I have a class with the method `get_class` which includes a file relative to the current class

I call the method multiple times from in the class (always same instance of the class) but sometimes the relative path to the current class is not working/changed?

Seems strange.. If I put the relative path to the working directory (CWD) like `'php/map/app/'.$type.'/'.$name.'.php'` it always works

What could cause this?

The method is called from the same instance of the class and same PHP process/request, so it seems strange the relative path only works sometimes (it changes)

The script is always executed from the same origin `/some-dir/inde.php`

```
private function get_class(string $type, string $name): string{
    $name = ucfirst($name);
    $file = 'map/app/'.$type.'/'.$name.'.php';

    if(!include_once $file){
        throw new Error('File missing: '.$file);
    }

    return '\\dbdata\\'.$type.'\\'.$name;
}
```

Comment: You are probably working in the different folder. Also, what are you trying to achieve, some kind of semi-autoload?  Use spl_autoload_register instead ...

Comment: The method is called from the same instance of the class, so it seems strange the relative path only works sometimes..

Comment: Relative path starts from the script that was "launched".\

Comment: My script is ALWAYS executed from the same folder.. /some-dir/index.php

Comment: Why don't you want to use autoload?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this script from a folder different than where the included files are, it will fail.

Either look for files based on root path (adding / at the beginning) or use some kind of autoloader.

This could easily be managed by Composer, your composer.json file would look something like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "dbdata\\": "map/app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "any/additional/classes/to/map"
    ]
}
```

You need to ensure your php files are namespaced. Then you must also include `vendor/autoload.php` before accessing any of the mapped classes

Comment: It's ALWAYS executed from the same origin.. /some-dir/index.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `is_file()` and `include_once()` is not "working" in the same manner considering relative paths..

Everything is working as expected. I was testing with `is_file()`

Answer (score -1):

You need read:
1) Php namespaces
2) Php autoload class
3) Import class with namespaces

Simple example (classes folder /classes/autoload.php):

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    // convert namespace to full file path
    $class = 'classes/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    // Load class if exists
    if (file_exists($class)) {
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            require_once($class);   
        }
    }
});
```

Class example (classes/Auth/Login/Auth.php):

```
<?php
// Create namespace
namespace Auth\Login;

// import other class if needed
use Auth\Login\Mysql;

// class sample with or without extends
class Auth extends Mysql
{
     ... class methods here ...
}
?>
```

Then load class from namespaces (router.php):

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/autoload.php');
// Load class 
use Auth\Login\Auth;
try{
    $r = new Auth();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<h4 style="color: #222; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial">'.$e->getMessage().'<h4>';
}
?>
```

**Or just load from fullpath:**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-class/ClassName.php');
```

Comment: I don't want to use autoload in this case

Comment: You have answer here require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-class/ClassName.php');

Comment: I already have the that answer myself.. But I want to understand why the relative path only works some times

Comment: read what does it mean "relative" only from current folder (folder with your .php file  and subfolders) !!!

Comment: You doesn't really answer my question